# Can I disable Heroku's slugignore?

Tags: heroku

I understand that Heroku removes the `.git` directory as part of reducing the size of its slug

Is there a way to disable that?

Comment: You're asking two different things. The `.slugignore` has nothing to do with your `.git/` directory being present or not. To "disable" the `.slugignore`, simply don't include it.

Comment: Now, what are you trying to do with your `.git/` directory at runtime? This might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627).

Comment: indeed was an XY problem;
I needed to be able to access the date of a git commit;
ended up creating a `.profile` file and assigned the evaluated results as an env variable